# Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized C#

Tags: c#, database-connection, connection-string

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    cmd.CommandText="select id from regtb where id="+Session["id"];
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(dt);
    if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("userlogin.aspx");

    }

    }
```

What is wrong with this code?
can anybody help me on this
i am getting this error and i dont know how to correct this.

Comment: Don't use a mdf database file.  Use the name of the database in the server.  You can have credential issues access the mdf file directly.  I would make sure you have the proper credentials by using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and try a query from SSMS to make sure the connection is correct.  Then use the server name that is in the SSMS login window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to open your SqlConnection and then assign it to the SqlCommand:

```
                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;
```